# Service Temporarily Unavailable under load in OpenShift Enterprise 2.0

Tags: apache, openshift

Using OpenShift Enterprise 2.0, I have a simple jbossews (tomcat7) + mysql 5.1 app that uses JSP files connected to a mysql database. The app was created as a non-scaled app (fwiw the same issue happens when scaling is enabled).

Using a JMeter driver with only a single concurrent user and no think time, it will chug along for about 2 minutes (at about 200 req/sec) and then it will start returning "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" in batches (a few seconds at a time) on and off for the remainder of the test. Even if I change nothing (don't restart the app) if I wait a moment and then try again, it will do the same thing--first it seems fine, but then it will start with the errors.

The gear is far from fully-utilized (memory/cpu), and the only log I can find that shows a problem is the /var/log/httpd/error_log, which fills up with these entries:

```
[Tue Mar 25 15:51:13 2014] [error] (99)Cannot assign requested address: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.8.162.129:8080 (*) failed
```

Looking at the 'top' command on the node host at the time that the errors start to occur, I see several httpd processes surge to the top on and off.

So it looks like I am somehow running out of proxy connections or something similar. However, I'm not sure how that is happening with only a single concurrent user. Any ideas of how to fix this? I couldn't find any similar posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is that the system is running out of ephemeral ports due to connections stuck in TIME_WAIT. Check using:

```
netstat -pan --tcp | less
```

or

```
netstat -pan --tcp | grep -c ".*TIME_WAIT"
```

to just count the number of connections in time wait state.

These are connections made by the node port proxy (httpd) to the tomcat backend. There are several ways to change TCP settings in order to lessen the problem. First attempt is to enable reuse. Append the following to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
# allow reuse of time_wait connections
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
```

This will allow connections in TIME_WAIT state to be reused if there are no ephemeral ports available.

However,the problem mostly remains that these connections are not being properly pooled. I do not run into this issue outside of a gear with the same app+driver--meaning that the connections are properly pooled and don't have to sit in TIME_WAIT state at all. Something in the proxy must be interfering with the connection closure.

Looks like the mod_proxy / mod_rewrite are not configured for connection pooling/keepalive or they are not compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should first try and move to vhost routing, if your hitting this issue, but tcp tw reuse can help if vhost connection are still so high that you still run out of port.

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1203843 also has a lot of good information on the topic, including this on possible causes of error 503:

> Understanding that HAProxy preforms health checks on Gear
> (application) contexts is important because if these checks fail you
> can see 502 or 503 errors when trying to access your application,
> because the Proxy disables the route to the application (IE: puts the
> gear in maintenance mode).

...and...

> ...if you are seeing 502 or 503 errors when trying to access your
> application, it could be because the proxy is disabling the routes to
> the application (IE: puts the gear in maintenance mode), because it is
> failing health checks...